# Error using the makeRegrTask function from the MLR package

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, feature-selection

I am trying to do feature selection using the MLR package. Here is my code:

```
#Feature Extraction
features.task = makeRegrTask(id = "cr", data = final1, target = "spam")
feature_selection= generateFilterValuesData(features.task, method = "information.gain")
plotFilterValues(feature_selection)
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
> features.task = makeRegrTask(id = "cr", data = final1, target = "spam")
Error in (function (cn, x)  : 
  Unsupported feature type (character) in column 'host'.
```

What should I be doing to solve this error? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `host` column contains character (string) values, but `makeRegrTask` expects to see only the response variable and predictors in whatever you pass in as `data`.

From the [docs](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/mlr/mlr.pdf):

> `data`: A data frame containing the features and target variable

If you intend for `host` to be a categorical predictor, you'll need to create dummy variables representing each level.  Otherwise, drop `host` before passing `final1` into `makeRegrTask`.

Answer (score 0):

If `host` is a character variable then you should first convert it to a factor. `mlr` can deal with factors.

Possible code is:

```
data = final1 %>% mutate_at(vars(one_of("host")), funs( as.factor)) 
data = final1 %>% mutate_if(sapply(data_test, is.character), as.factor)
```

Note that this is `dplyr` code. With the first line you can add column names that you would like to convert to factor beofer passing it to the task. The second converts all character columns.